# areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled' is deprecated

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I set this firestore db setting like this

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
let settings = db.settings
settings.areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled = true // <--- the problem in this line
db.settings = settings
```

but it is said that

> areTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled' is deprecated

so what should I do ?

Comment: You should be able to just remove that line, as its behavior is now the standard behavior of newer SDK versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation [FirebaseFirestore Framework Reference
FirestoreSettings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/FirestoreSettings) informs:

> Specifies whether to use FIRTimestamps for timestamp fields in FIRDocumentSnapshots. This is now enabled by default and should not be disabled.

So, you don't need to declare this line anymore, only if you want to opt-out of this feature, where you would set to `false` this parameter on the API.

Let me know if the information helped you!

Comment: Thanks.. Their documentation says "@deprecated This setting now defaults to true and will be removed in a future release. If you are already setting it to true, just remove the setting. If you are setting it to false, you should update your code to expect FIRTimestamp objects instead of NSDate and then remove the setting."